# Puzzling message from Startup Disk Creator

Tags: startup-disk

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 and I want to use Startup Disk Creator.  But when it starts up it shows a box with the puzzling message "Installing ?" and a progress bar.  If I cancel it, SDC terminates.  What is that message all about, and how can I get past it?

Comment: It is correct that progress has been made to fix this. While you wait for it to land in the repositories, you can try the preliminary fix in this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~wxl/+archive/ubuntu/staging/+packages

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Specifically [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1629715) which has a patch to fix it, but hasn't been applies in Ubuntu yet.